# Hazelcast 'IdentifiedDataSerializable': writeData HashMap instance

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I've started using Hazelcast's IdentifiedDataSerializable interface to serialize some classes and something is not working right when I need to writeData a simple java.util.map instance - I do it using

```
out.writeObject(map_inst);
```

but it throws an exception: `java.io.NotSerializableException`

If I store only a single entry of the map as follow:

```
out.writeObject(map_inst.get(0));
```

then it works!

What am I missing here?

Another question:
in my class I have the following declaration:

```
private static final int FRACTION = 0.1;
```

Do I need to `writeData\readData` `'static final'` members?
or because they are `static` there is no need?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you are using a `HashMap`? Also are the keys of the map serializable?

Comment: it's a `ConcurrentHashMap`  but it's the same. and YES - the key of the map is a plain `Long`.

Comment: I've found this reference in Hazelcast Google Group:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/hazelcast/serialize$20hashmap%7Csort:relevance/hazelcast/0LYLNBAtxMs/sBkDHBRnDgAJ